# "Site cant be reached" error. When running Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I am facing an error when running docker container on port 5000 on localhost. I deployed a fastapi Machine learning model and want to run it using docker container.
Error:

```
This site can’t be reached
The web page at http://0.0.0.0:5000/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.8
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "5000"]
```

Command I am running for docker to build container:

```
docker build -t tags:latest .
```

Command to run docker container I am using:

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 tags:latest
```

Comment: That is strange. I'd expect the docker container to be a http server - yet the error message you show looks like coming from a client. Where did you get the error from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are getting the error message from a client (e.g. your browser on the same machine):

When you open a server socket for IP 0.0.0.0 it means it opens that server socket on all interfaces.
When you connect with a client to a server, you need to give a concise address, such as 127.0.0.1 or one of the configured IPs for that machine. Connecting to 0.0.0.0 should always result in an error message.